# Generate Columns based on number of templates in User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I'm trying to create an ASP.NET UserControl that generates a CSS grid of columns based on the number of templates specified when the control is added to a page.

At the moment it is very simple in its implementation and I'm unsure how to expand this to use more columns.

### Markup (LayoutGrid.ascx)

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LayoutGrid.ascx.cs" Inherits="PinnacleSideNav.Controls.LayoutGrid" %>

<div class="grid">    
    <div class="col2">
        <div class="colContent">
            <asp:Placeholder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolderColumn" />
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

### Code Behind (LayoutGrid.ascx.cs)

```
using System.Web.UI;

namespace PinnacleSideNav.Controls
{
    [ParseChildren(true)]

    public partial class LayoutGrid : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        private ITemplate column = null;

        [TemplateContainer(typeof(TemplateControl))]
        [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
        [TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)]
        public ITemplate Column
        {
            get
            {
                return column;
            }
            set
            {
                column = value;
            }
        }    

        void Page_Init()
        {
            if (column != null)
                column.InstantiateIn(PlaceHolderColumn);
        }
    }
}
```

### Registration (Web.Config)

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="control" src="~/Controls/LayoutGrid.ascx" tagName="layout"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
```

### Implementation Example

```
<control:layout runat="server">
    <column>
        This is column 1
    </column>
    <column>
        This is column 2
    </column>
    <column>
        This is column 3
    </column>
</control:layout>
```

The example above works for 1 template but ideally I would like the number of `<column>`s used to define how many columns will appear.

### Desired Output

```
<div class="grid">    
    <div class="col3"> <!--This class would be generated based on the number of Templates used-->
        <div class="colContent">
            This is column 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col3">
        <div class="colContent">
            This is column 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col3">
        <div class="colContent">
            This is column 3
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```